# Using a random point in two actions

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

Sorry I'm new to this.
Right now I'm trying to create an endless randomly moving sprite that rotates to its direction. However I can't figure out how to use the random location generated from randomPoint on the rotateAction. Basically the bug randomly rotates instead of using the point it's going to. Is there a way I can use the same random point twice?

```
-(void)moveRandom:(CCSprite*)roach
{

    CGPoint randomPoint = ccp(arc4random()%480, arc4random()%320);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(randomPoint));

    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int randomDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    float dY = roach.position.y - randomPoint.y;
    float dX = roach.position.x - randomPoint.x;
    float offset = dX<0 ? 90.0f : -90.0f;
    float angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2f(dY, dX)) + offset;

    [roach runAction:
     [CCActionSequence actions:
      [CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.001 angle:angle],
      [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:randomDuration position: randomPoint],
      [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
         [self performSelector:@selector(moveRandom:) withObject:roach afterDelay:0.5];
     }],
      nil]
     ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things that stand out: It looks like you're trying to get the angle in the wrong direction. The conditional offset is not needed. radians to degrees should be negated .. I'm guessing you want:

```
float dY = randomPoint.y - roach.position.y;
float dX = randomPoint.x - roach.position.x;
float angle = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2f(dY, dX));
```